# Can I publish my tomcat instance to other computers in the same wifi network? How about the internet?

Tags: java, tomcat

**SCENARIO:** Tomcat instance running in one Windows 7 machine, 1 application published.

**OBJECTIVE 1:** Provide access to this instance on another computer on the same WIFI network

**THINGS TRIED:** From the client computer, tried accessing `http://<IPofComputerWithTomcat>:8080/`, `http://hostnameofComputerWithTomcat:8080`, page cannot be found.

**GOAL 2:** Provide access to this instance outside the local network, ie. the internet

**TRIED:** No idea how to begin.

Comment: Using the default configuration, tomcat will accept connections from all sources, including other ips in the same wifi, *and* from the internet, so unless you changed the configuration the source of the problem is most likely a firewall on your machine that must be "instructed" to let call directed at the tomcat port pass, or something like that.

Comment: Is your application deployed to the "ROOT" folder inside of your Tomcat? Otherwise add the applications name to the url: host:8080/MyApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably better asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/),

I guess your Tomcat binds to the Local Interface and thus is not accessible from the outside world.

If you would like to make Tomcat serve requests from any other host (same wifi network AND the internet), change your Connector in the server.xml config file (See [official Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) for details)

```
    <Connector port="8080" 
       protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       address="0.0.0.0"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

The important part is `address="0.0.0.0"` which binds your tomcat to all network interfaces.

It this is already in place there might also be a firewall or other windows networking settings blocking incoming requests.

If you can reach Tomcat, but get an error message such as 404 not found, make sure you are using the correct URL:

```
http://<TomcatHostOrIP>:8080/Context/
```

Where Context is usually the name of your war-file.